# Como ajustar setas de navegação

Tags: css

Preciso ajustar setas de navegação de uma página que tenho, mas todas as alterações que faço não consigo deixa-la de forma correta, preciso inicialmente deixa-las maior e defini o tamanho como *36px* por *34px*, o tamanho ficou correto, mas não estou conseguindo deixar as setas centralizadas e com um espaçamento entre elas que facilite a navegação em dispositivos móveis.

O que tenho é isso:

```css
.jcarousel-prev, .jcarousel-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
    background-image: url(images/carousel-arrows.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.jcarousel-prev {
    right: 20px;
    background-position: 7px 5px;
}

.jcarousel-next {
    right: 0;
    background-position: -18px 5px; 
}
```

E que tentei fazer foi isso:

```css
.jcarousel-prev, .jcarousel-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 34px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
    background-image: url(images/carousel-arrows.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.jcarousel-prev {
    right: 35px;
    background-position: 7px 13px;
}

.jcarousel-next {
    right: 0;
    background-position: -18px 13px;    
}
```

Esse é o primeiro projeto que foco em CSS, minha área é a de programação, por isso a grande dificuldade.

Página para visualização do exemplo:
[Página com alteração nos ítens Mais fotos desse produto e Mais fotos camas](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/detalhes.php?produto=77&dep=2&sub=6)

Comment: Eu usei `background-position: 15px 13px;` no `.jcarousel-prev` e `background-position: -10px 13px` no `.jcarousel-next` e ficou centralizado. Talvez seja interessante você procurar uma fonte de ícones que facilita muita a utilização e contém vários ícones disponíveis, como por exemplo, o [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/).

Comment: Olá @Oeslei, muito obrigado pela ajuda, o tamanho e a centralização ficaram legas, mas como posso deixa-los com um espaçamento entre eles?

Comment: Você alterou a propriedade `right` do `.jcarousel-prev`. Deixe como estava antes, com `35px` que fica certo =)

Comment: Se quiser deixar um espaço, aumente o valor da propriedade `right`, não diminua =).

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso, muito obrigado @Oeslei sua ajuda foi de grande valia.

Comment: @adventistapr se o problema foi resolvido poste a sua solução como resposta. Pode ser que a forma como você resolveu seja a mesma para futuras perguntas referentes ao mesmo assunto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo a sugestão feita fiz as alterações necessários e venho colocar o código alterado como resposta devidamente comentado nos pontos onde as alterações foram feitas.

```css
/* Setas laterais dos thumbs */
.jcarousel-prev, .jcarousel-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    /* Aqui defini a nova altura e largura */
    width: 36px;
    height: 34px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
    background-image: url(images/carousel-arrows.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.jcarousel-prev {
    /* Aqui defini o novoe espaçamento entre as setas */
    right: 45px;
    /* Posição da seta "Anterior" */
    background-position: 15px 13px;
}

.jcarousel-next {
    right: 0;
    /* Posição da seta "Próxima" */
    background-position: -10px 13px 
}
```

Agradeço aos que me ajudaram.